# checkbox value in dynamic webform

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a dynamic created form and i will get the value of some checkboxes. but I have problems with the index of the returned values ​​for checkboxes

```
                    <div id="clonedim">
                    <div class="panel" id="tabdim">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="large-12 columns">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                                        <label>Zusätzliche Angaben:</label><br> 
                                        <input type="hidden" name="fachanwalt[]" value="no"/>
                                        <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="fachanwalt[]"><label class="checkbox-label" name="lblfachanwalt[]">Fachanwaltstitel</label>

                                        <input type="hidden" name="zwang[]" value="no"/>
                                        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" value="yes" name="zwang[]"><label class="checkbox-label" name="lblzwang[]">Tätigkeit als Zwangsverwalter</label>

                                        <input type="hidden" name="brief[]" value="no"/>
                                        <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" value ="yes" name="brief[]"><label class="checkbox-label" name="lblbrief[]">Außenauftritt (Briefpapier)</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the function to expand the form:

```
function clone_this_dim() {
    var cldim = document.getElementById('clonedim');
    var tabdim = document.getElementById('tabdim');
    //var newrow = tabdim.lastChild.cloneNode(true);

    var newrow = tabdim.cloneNode(true);
    LineCount = LineCount + 1;

    for (x = 0; x < newrow.getElementsByTagName('input').length; x++) {
         newrow.getElementsByTagName('input')[x].value = '';
    }

    for (x = 0; x < newrow.getElementsByTagName('select').length; x++) {
         newrow.getElementsByTagName('select')[x].value = '';
    }

    for (x = 0; x < newrow.getElementsByTagName('label').length; x++) {
         newrow.getElementsByTagName('label')[x].value = '';
    }

    cldim.appendChild(newrow);
}
```

the name of checkbox and hidden field must be equal. At the moment, the index values ​​are different.
somebody has an idea how I can improve it?

Comment: please, be more specific. What problems are hou having?

Comment: I think you're missing some significant context regarding your script

Comment: What do you want to improve, and why are u using values in the `name` attributes more than once?

Comment: so I get a return value when the checkbox is not selected